# Exponentiation modulo trick

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's say I have

$p, g$ - known constant, $p$ is prime number, $g$ is composite.

$x$ - unknown random number, $2 < x < p - 1$

$k$ - my input

$S = k^x \bmod p$

$1 < S < p-1$

So, what $k$ should I use to make $S$ predictable? I mean, I want to know exactly what is $S$ equal to.

Comment: Why did you define $g$, is it a generator and $S=g^k$?

Comment: Hint: your first step is to find small to moderates factors of $(p-1)/2$. On second thought, $g$ will help, though you certainly can do without.

Comment: $g$ can be used for guessing $S$, but is not used anywhere in calculations.

Comment: $(p - 1) / 2$ has only two factors, but I don't know what to do next

Comment: If $(p-1)/2$ is prime, well, there's no much you can do; any way of reducing the possible number of values of $S$ would depend on a small factor of $p-1$, and if $k=1$ and $k=p-1$ (which uses the factor 2) are not available, you're stuck.

Comment: No, $(p - 1)/2$ is composite, but it has only two [prime factors](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=+51561019934674150654137415596329461689439533432255114577281168216151321693032481231698109780741261076338236177986142349540172305117250758393483062787886749686161804350462147320169983168295304444999873413717624347922360645775567138482924711268980216489609254923940452352938115198301097387510540611965667433531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p-1$ has a factor of 348419, then you could reduce the number of possible values of $S$ to 348418 (or 1, which you said was not allowed).

One way to do this would be to pick a random value $r$, and compute $k = r^{(p-1)/348419} \bmod p$; if $k$ is something other than 1, then that's your value; the eventual $S$ value will be $k^x \bmod p$ for some $1 \le x < 348419$.

For this particular $p$ (and the constraints you have listed), that's the best you can do.

Comment: It worked (I used $r=2$), thank you very much

Comment: Yes, this is the way and a nice addition that the probability of a random value will not be 1 is $(p-1)/348418$, right?

Comment: @kelalaka: actually, the probability that it's not 1 is $1 - 1/348419$